# Ways to export or query all hospitals from Open Street Map

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

How can I export or query all hospitals from Open Street Map?

I'd like to extract all the hospital locations in the from Open Street Map as a reference for my little geocoding project.
I know how to get all the OSM data for a small area with the QGIS plugin but not sure how to query a larger area  eg for the whole planet-file?

Some ideas:

1. The read-only Overpass API. I don't know that it'll work for the whole planet-file in one pass, but maybe if we extend the time out enough?
   For a smaller area and with the benefit of a (minimal) UI, we can access Overpass via the XAPI Query Builder. There, we can put amenity=hospital in the tag search, select our area, and go.
2. Geofabrik downloads, filtered with Osmosis, as described in How to extract partial data for large regions? on the OpenStreetMap Help.
3. What about using healthsites.io:  regarding healthsites this is the most important link: https://healthsites.io/api/docs
   can i use healthsites.io for my project!?

I want to maintain the dataset in a PostgreSQL db.

**update:** btw: when trying to get the data from overpass-turbo i get somewhat full set of POI data

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","website"," contact:email=*")][timeout:600];

area["ISO3166-1"="AT"]->.a;

( node(area.a)[amenity=hospital];

  way(area.a)[amenity=hospital];

  rel(area.a)[amenity=hospital];);

out;
```

see the results:

```
@id    @type    name    addr:postcode    addr:city    addr:street    addr:housenumber    website     contact:email=*
2656877    relation    Unfallkrankenhaus Lorenz Böhler    1200    Wien    Donaueschingenstraße    13    https://www.auva.at/ukhboehler/   
2685003    relation    Landeskrankenhaus Hörgas-Enzenbach                    http://www.lkh-hoergas.at   
2685004    relation    Landeskrankenhaus Judenburg-Knittelfeld                    http://www.lkh-judenburg.at   
2685005    relation    Landeskrankenhaus Hochsteiermark                    http://www.lkh-hochsteiermark.at   
2685006    relation    Landeskrankenhaus Mürzzuschlag-Mariazell                    http://www.lkh-muerzzuschlag.at   
2685007    relation    Landeskrankenhaus Rottenmann-Bad Aussee                    http://www.lkh-rottenmann.at   
2755244    relation    Landesklinikum Scheibbs    3270    Scheibbs    Feldgasse    26       
2764083    relation    Allgemeines Krankenhaus Wien    1090    Wien    Währinger Gürtel    18-20    https://www.akhwien.at   
2882269    relation    Unfallkrankenhaus Salzburg                    http://www.ukh-salzburg.at   
3333391    relation    Krankenhaus St. Josef    5280    Braunau am Inn    Ringstraße    60    https://www.khbr.at/   
4460484    relation    Landeskrankenhaus Graz II                    http://www.lkh-graz-sw.at   
6704364    relation    Landesklinikum Neunkirchen            Peischingerstraße    19    https://www.neunkirchen.lknoe.at/   
9522773    relation    Krankenhaus der Barmherzigen Brüder    7000    Eisenstadt    Esterhazystraße    26       
11077211    relation    "Landeskrankenhaus Murtal, Standort Stolzalpe Haus 1"    8852    Stolzalpe    Stolzalpe    38    https://www.lkh-murtal.at/
```

or to take a second example:

```
30850910    way Hôpital Nord Guillaume et René Laennec  44093   Nantes Cedex 1  Bd professeur Jacques-Monod - Saint-Herblain        https://www.chu-nantes.fr/  
30979413    way Hôpital Albert Chenevier    94010   Créteil rue de Mesly    40  http://chu-mondor.aphp.fr/hopital-albert-chenevier1/    
31150222    way Centre de Psychiatrie Les Tournesols                        
31150223    way Clinique du Saint-Coeur                 http://www.saint-coeur.groupe-elsan.com/    
31252310    way Hôpital Avicenne                    http://chu93.aphp.fr/hopital-avicenne-bobigny/  
32229408    way Centre hospitalier du Rouvray   76300   Sotteville-lès-Rouen    Rue Paul Éluard 4   www.ch-lerouvray.fr 
32354044    way Centre hospitalier intercommunal Fréjus Saint-Raphaël                   https://www.chi-fsr.fr/ 
32388820    way Clinique des Cèdres                 https://clinique-cedres.capio.fr/   
32471086    way Hôpital Saint-Jacques                       
32522247    way Centre hospitalier de Dieppe    76200   Dieppe  Avenue Pasteur      http://www.ch-dieppe.fr 
32617022    way Hôpital Désandrouins    55100   Verdun  Avenue d'Étain          
32679701    way Hôpital Belle-Isle                  https://www.hpmetz.fr/fr/etablissement/hopital-belle-isle   
32851894    way Clinique d'Occitanie    31600   Muret   Avenue Bernard IV   20  http://www.clinique-occitanie.com/  
32940084    way Centre hospitalier de Longjumeau                    http://www.gh-nord-essonne.fr/accueil.aspx  
33061296    way Clinique de l'Yvette                        
33533346    way Hôpital privé de l'Est Lyonnais                 https://hpel.fr/    
33624453    way Clinique de l'Union                 https://clinique-union-toulouse.ramsaygds.fr/   
33639902    way Hôpital du Hasenrain                        
33826818    way Hôpital du Croisic                      
33889337    way Centre Hospitalier Guy Thomas                   http://ch-riom.fr/  
33916780    way Hôpital Émile Muller                        
34426829    way Centre hospitalier de Pau                   https://www.ch-pau.fr/  
34428388    way Clinique Princess                   http://www.clinique-princess.com/   
34428389    way Centre Hospitalier Spécialisé des Pyrénées                      
34478129    way Pôle Santé République                   http://www.psr.groupe-elsan.com/    
34571025    way Centre hospitalier d'Albi                   http://www.ch-albi.fr/  
34965024    way Hôpital de la Conception                    http://fr.ap-hm.fr/nos-hopitaux/hopital-de-la-conception    
35049042    way Hôpital Simone Veil                 https://www.hopital-simoneveil.fr/  
35051383    way Centre hospitalier intercommunal André Grégoire                 http://www.chi-andre-gregoire.fr/   
35539378    way Hôpital Jean Verdier                    http://chu93.aphp.fr/hopital-jean-verdier-bondy/    
36787144    way Centre hospitalier de Die                   http://www.ch-die.fr/   
36894682    way Hopital Beaujon 92110   Clichy  Boulevard du Général Leclerc    100 http://hupnvs.aphp.fr/beaujon/  
36962284    way Centre Hospitalier de Pfastatt                      
37097582    way Centre hospitalier Comminges Pyrénées                   http://www.ch-saintgaudens.fr/chcp17/index.php/fr/  
37099012    way Hôpital d'Instruction des Armées Bégin                      
37108859    way Centre hospitalier Comminges Pyrénées   31800   Saint-Gaudens   Boulevard d'Encore  21      
37135205    way Centre hospitalier de Pontarlier                    http://pontarlier-hopital.chi-hautecomte.fr/    
37216610    way Centre hospitalier                  http://www.ch-chateauroux.fr/   
37678740    way Clinique du Château                 http://www.clinique-garches.com/    
37836452    way Centre de Gérontologie et d'Accueil Spécialisé Philippe Dugué                   http://www.hgchevreuse.fr/  
38072526    way Hôpital Bichat-Claude Bernard                   http://hupnvs.aphp.fr/  
38076764    way Clinique du Château de Florans                      
38237520    way Centre Hospitalier Intercommunal des Alpes du Sud                   http://www.chicas-gap.fr    
38237900    way Centre psychothérapique Camille Claudel                     
38480566    way Centre hospitalier de Béziers           Rue Valentin Haüy   2   http://www.ch-beziers.fr    
38496996    way Centre hospitalier intercommunal de Cornouaille 29000   Quimper Avenue Yves Thépot  14  https://www.ch-cornouaille.fr/  
38496997    way Polyclinique Quimper-Sud        Quimper Rue Gustave Flaubert        http://quimper-sud.clinique-quimper.fr/fr   
38568780    way Centre Cardiologique d'Évecquemont                      
38701149    way Centre Hospitalier de Chauny                        
38867555    way Centre hospitalier Eure-Seine   27200   Vernon  Rue du Docteur Burnet   5   http://www.chi-eureseine.fr 
38918952    way Centre hospitalier de Hyères            Boulevard du Maréchal Juin  579 http://www.ch-hyeres.fr 
39215839    way Centre hospitalier de Saint-Affrique                    http://ch-saintaffrique.fr/ 
39255826    way Hôpital de Prades                       
39489000    way Clinique de Girardin                        
39536410    way Centre hospitalier intercommunal de Poissy                  http://www.chi-poissy-st-germain.fr/fr/Page-d-accueil-167.html  
39947896    way Clinique Saint-Louis                        
40199116    way Clinique Notre-Dame                     
40282457    way Hôpital Delafontaine                    http://www.ch-stdenis.fr    
40283884    way Centre hospitalier Jacques Lacarin  03200   Vichy   Boulevard Denière   1   http://www.ch-vichy.fr/ 
40358353    way Clinique Sainte-Marguerite                      
40467444    way Clinique Villa Magali                       
40503994    way Clinique Générale                   http://www.clinique-generale.net/fr/documents/p_accueil.html    
40593554    way Clinique Sainte-Marie                   https://chpsaintemarie.fr/le-chp/pole-sante-osny/   
40610772    way Hôpital du Porzou                   http://www.ch-cornouaille.fr/ch-quimper-concarneau/infos-pratiques/plan-dacces/concarneau-site-du-porzou    
40667164    way Hôpital Civil   67091   Strasbourg  Place de l'Hôpital  1   http://www.chru-strasbourg.fr/index.php 
40686020    way Centre de Soins et d'Accompagnement et de Prévention en Addictologie
```

if you look here - this is much much more incomplete

https://healthsites.io/map#!/locality/node/4777740642

no complete adress - no website etc. etx.

conclusio: should i stick to a request with overpass-turbo.eu - is this more appropiate?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to download data from healthsites anyway:

1. Go to https://healthsites.io/map
2. *Download all healthsite data in this World.zip (last update at : ...)* --> click on "World.zip" to download that file.

Comment: hello MMD - many thanks i will do as adviced - and import all that OSM-data to PostGIS for the purpose of visualization and further analytics.There are a bunch of tools on the market— osm2pgsql; imposm; ogr2org; just to mention some of those.
i will do any further steps according this manual: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/open-street-map-to-postgis-the-basics/